# When using id's by jquery to do something, can the id's come from any kind of tag?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery, and I am attempting writing code using PHP, HTML, and JQuery.

I want to replace all of the `<?php echo $var; ?>` in my HTML with tags that have id's, instead. For example, I want to have something like `<div id="name"></div>` which would then use a `$("#name")` to have it display something in that div field.

My questions: 
Does it have to be a `<div>` tag with that id when I call the `#name` in jquery? Or can it be in any tag and still have the same effect? --Would this work as well: `<a href='alink'><div id="name"></div></a>`. 
What if I want to put tags with id's to replace the `alink`--What tags would be good for that?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an id to any field.  However, you can only use that particular id ONCE per page.

Ex.

```
<div id="name"></div>
<p id="name"></div>
<a id="name"></a>
```

The above is invalid and will cause problems if you use `$('#name')` in your jQuery.  If you want to alter multiple things, like shown above, you are better off using a class and a different kind of selector:

```
<div class="name"></div>
<p class="name"></div>
<a class="name"></a>

$('.name')
```

This will select both of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

An `id` can be an attribute of any html tag (element).

It also must be completely unique to the html document at any given time.

`<?php echo $var; ?>` however is not html at all, it is [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php) which is something separate all together.

Comment: I am trying to do this: `<a href =<element id="link"></element> target="_blank"><element id="name"></element></a>` but it shows up as "target="_blank">" which links to "<element". And if i try putting quotes around `'<element id="link"></element>'`, then it links to that literally. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: So is my only option to do the `<?php echo $link; ?>` after the `href=` ? Would it not be bad practice to be inconsistant?

Comment: again, you're mixing up PHP and HTML, so yeah, just do `href="<?php echo $link; ?>"`

Comment: I am not mixing up PHP and HTML. I meant inconsistent in terms of determining what is to be displayed using both PHP AND something that is output by a JQuery post, for example. I was asking, and sorry if I was unclear, whether I should just give this whole tag/id thing, up and be consistant by using the `<?php echo $...;?>`.

Comment: There is absolutely **no** relation between html tag's id attribute and echoing out php variables...

Comment: That is not what i was saying. I was saying `<a href =<?php echo $link; ?> ><element id="name"></element></a>` vs. `<a href =<?php echo $link; ?> ><?php echo $name; ?></a>` And asking, which one is preferable in terms of code being cleaner--or what the convention was.

Answer (score 1):

It can be any tag (=element), not just divs.